# Apply filter to WordPress shortcode output

Tags: wordpress, shortcode

I would like to modify the shortcode output of a WordPress plugin.

I have tried the following:

```
$myShortcode = do_shortcode('[print_responsive_thumbnail_slider id="1"]');
echo apply_filters('new_shortcode_filter',$myShortcode);


add_filter('new_shortcode_filter','new_shortcode_filter_callback');

function new_shortcode_filter_callback($myShortcode){
    //modify content right here

    return $modifiedContent;
}
```

Unfortunately the filter isn't applied on the shortcode output.

If I do it like this to override the shortcode and to modifiy the output there will be a infinite loop caused by the do_shortcode function:

```
function update_shortcode_slider_content() {
    $sliderContent = do_shortcode('[print_responsive_thumbnail_slider id="1"]');;
    //some magic

    return $modifiedSliderContent;
}
add_shortcode('print_responsive_thumbnail_slider', 'update_shortcode_slider_content');
```

Did I do something wrong or is there another/better way to modify the output of a shortcode?

Comment: Try adding your filter before applying it

Comment: Thank you. Now the filter is applied on the shortcode, but the modified shortcode output is now added at the top of the page and there is still the unmodified shortcode output at the correct position. I just want to have the modified output on my page at the correct position. Could you please tell me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 10):

WordPress 4.7 introduced a new filter, do_shortcode_tag, to do exactly this. https://www.shawnhooper.ca/2017/01/do-shortcode-tag/